# Cognos default package for template

Tags: templates, package, cognos

I'm trying to find a way to improve our self-serve reporting experience. I'd like to be able to have a default package applied when selecting a specific template. Is there functionality to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what version of Cognos you are using.  In 11.0.7, the answer is, "No."  When you create a report and choose a template, any package information in the template is ignored.

Alternative:  You can provide "template" reports with more configuration that the user can copy to their folder then edit.  Or they can open it in place, edit as needed, run, then discard.

Comment: We're using 11.0.8, I'm sure that isn't much of a difference. That answers my question. Thanks.